# Set font for whole page with ONLY html

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to set a global font for a web page using only HTML? I can't use CSS, because this is for a school project. Something like: `<body font = verdana>...content...</body>`

Comment: Heya, welcome to Stack Overflow. It's typically expected when asking questions that you include your research, attempted solutions, etc. Be specific about what your problem is with any earlier ideas / attempts.

Comment: If you use HTML5, the only way to change the font is by using css. Can't you just do <body style="font-family: verdana"> ?

Comment: note that even when you're writing `font = verdana`  - you're using css!

Comment: Have A look at my new updated answer with no css

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The way to do it in HTML with inline styles would be:

```
<body style="font-family: sans-serif">
```

This will set the global font to `sans-serif`

You can also put CSS inside a `<style>` tag like this:

```
<style>
    * {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
</style>
```

This will give every element a font of `sans-serif`

For custom fonts you can use [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts)

**Edit this is the way to achieve it with pure HTML:**

After the `<body>` tag, add the `<font>` tag with the face attribute of the font you'd like to use. Example usage:

Fiddle Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/yHRU7/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <font face='verdana'>
        <div class='htmlVersion'>No css</div>
    </font>
    <div class='cssVersion'>No Extra Html</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.cssVersion {
    font-family: verdana;
}
```

As you can see there is no difference between the results. I advise that  normal stylesheets are used - the method used in the CSS version. This is more maintainable and standard.

Comment: Of course, that's still css...

Comment: I know but I don't see why it is not possible for him to use

Comment: Me neither, but that is what he asked for... like all the people asking for javascript-not-jquery answers, and all the answers that are like "use jquery anyway". Yes, it is demonstrably the right answer to the real question, "how do you do [x]", but it's still not the right answer to the sillier question, "how do you do [x] without [y]", to which the real answer might (or might not) be "you don't".

Comment: @neminem found a way didn't know it was possible

Answer (score 7):

You can apply css in html with [inline css](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) but it's highly recommanded to use an external stylesheet

```
<body style="font-family:'Verdana'">
```

Comment: This doesn't set the font for all elements! See [live](http://jsfiddle.net/Al_Bundy/c6j03zum/). The `select` item doesn't have the correct font and color. Using `html *` solves it